# Restrict value by date If function

Tags: mysql

Edited ** This is resolved now**

May I ask how to restrict the 'Sum_fee' to the dates in the query below. Id like to show count values based on different dates from columns. Normally I use where clauses but it doesn't work due to differing dates, but the below does for the count values.

However the Sum_fee column displays values from all years, I'm really trying to make it display only sums as defined in the query.

```
    Select
        c.Adviser,
        Count(If(Year(l.LeadDate) = Year(Now()) And Month(l.LeadDate) = Month(Now()), 1, Null)) As Leads,
        Count(If(Year(l.signedupdate) = Year(Now()) And Month(l.signedupdate) = Month(Now()), 1, Null)) As Written,
        Count(If(Year(l.CompDate) = Year(Now()) And Month(l.CompDate) = Month(Now()), 1, Null)) As Completed,
**SUM (If(Year(l.CompDate) = Year(Now()) And Month(l.CompDate) = Month(Now()), (l.broker_fee) + (l.comms), 0)) As sum_fees**
    From
        mortga01_portal.tbl_clients c Inner Join
        mortga01_portal.tbl_lead l On l.client_id = c.client_id
    Group By
        c.Adviser
    Having
        Count(If(Year(l.LeadDate) = Year(Now()) And Month(l.LeadDate) = Month(Now()), 1, Null)) > 1
```

Comment: Please provide sample data, expected results based on the sample data and the output based on your current query!

Comment: Sum_fee column summarises values from all rows as the expression does not have any filtering and there is no where clause in the query. Not sure what interval it should summarise - you have three different date fields there.

Comment: Yes, that's the bit I'm struggling with. I need the sum_fee to filter on the year now and monthly now too. If I add a where clause in any of the date columns it breaks the other 2 date columns. Id like to show lead counts, written counts, completed counts and fees in current year and current month. A single row will have a lead date and could have a Signed update or CompDate.

Comment: At what date is sum_fee payable? completion perhaps?

Comment: @gary as P.Salmon pointed out: this is primarily a business question as you need to define which date column to summarise fees by. Only you know this answer.

Comment: Thank you, it would be the completion date. On that date the fees are added.so ideally I'd sum the fees on CompDate, year now, month now. So, if we take today, I'd have a count of all leads entered in March 24, a count of those with a signed update and a count of those with a CompDate, then a sum of fees where CompDate is this year, this month.

Comment: Then it is the same calculation as you have for the completed column.

Comment: I tried to have the 3 dates in a where clause originally but that didn't work, as they conflicted with each other. Lead count was correct but signed update and CompDate wee incorrect.

Comment: You need to have the same conditional statement in you sum function as well, not just in the count.

Comment: This seems so straightforward that I cannot see where the difficulty is. On the other hand there is some ambiguity in that you may be looking for sum_fee where lead and completion are in the same period. You should clarify by publishing representative sample data and desired outcome as text.

Comment: Thank you, I took a break and came back to it, seems to work with this added. SUM (If(Year(l.CompDate) = Year(Now()) And Month(l.CompDate) = Month(Now()), (l.broker_fee) + (l.comms), 0)) As sum_fees. Appreciate your time.

Comment: The solution should be posted as an answer below, not by editing the question.